# navigation drawer activity is not available when I create a new application

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to create a Navigation Drawer in my application. I think by default template is available for that. But when I create a new application it is not showing the Navigation Drawer Activity.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because of **Min.SDK** and **Target SDK** that you set at the time of creating a new application.

Now If i try with **Min.SDK 4.0** and **Target SDK 4.4** i can see Navigation Drawer option.

One suggestion that I would like to given you that don't go with default navigation drawer as it has a lot of prob while customization.

So I recommend you to go with http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ this tutorial.it explains pretty well.